# Как считать regexp из файла?

Tags: node.js

Из файла считываю строки в массив,после циклом перебираю значения преобразуя их в RegExp: `re = new RegExp(key.toString(), 'gi');` и проверяю `re.test(some_text)`. Если задать RegExp вручную то все работает, но при считывании из файла нет (

Comment: использовать двойной обратный слеш вместо одинарного не забываете?

Comment: Вот пример строки из файла: `.*lifan x60$ `вроде ничего не нужно экранировать

Comment: `x60` - литералы или символ? Если второе, то требует двойной слеш

Comment: просто литералы

Comment: хм, тогда у меня кончились идеи ))

Comment: Сделал сравнение строки из фала и литералом через `===`, не равны

Comment: тоже была идея сделать так, но потом решил, что у вас в файле json со строками и тогда смысла в этом нет, если там просто текст, то могли затесаться всякие \n и прочее. Как с этим бороться к сожалению не смогу подсказать

Comment: `trim()` помог.

Comment: плохо понятно, каким образом вы считывали из файла ваше регулярное выражение; вероятно, просто в переменной key был перевод строки на конце, который trim как раз и убирает (вообще говоря, эта функция убирает _все_ пробельные символы по краям)

Answer (score 0):

Сделал `trim()` для всех переменных